# Custom syntax highlighting in VSCode Extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am currently trying to develop a VSCode extension that provides support for a new language. Static syntax highlighting should be provided by a TextMate file, additional semantic highlighting by a language server. Both of those use - for now - custom token types. The language server works nicely with Monaco and a corresponding Monarch syntax specification. With Monaco, I can set a theme manually via `monaco.editor.defineTheme` and provide rules for my custom tokens via `rules: [{token:'my.tokentype', foreground:...}]`, and as a result, I get syntax highlighting the way I want, and the rules work for both Monarch-defined tokens and semantic tokens.

Now I want to do the same for VSCode. The TextMate grammar and the language server provide textmate token types and semantic token types respectively, and I now want to provide (themable) default styles for my token types in my extension, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to make VSCode highlight a document in my language based on my token types. Using the tokens and scopes inspector, I can see that the tokens in my document are assigned the right "textmate scope" or "semantic token type".

Now, how can my extension style those tokens? I have found the `colors` contribution point, but that can only provide colors (not additional styling like `italic` etc) and I have no idea how to assign those colors to my token types...

the only way I got VSCode to highlight anything is by using the `semanticTokenTypes` contribution point and declaring a default `superType`, but of course in that case, it will use the highlighting associated with that superType, not anything provided by my extension...

Comment: the color of a token is determined in the theme file

Comment: I know, but there is no theme. I want to specify a default value that is used in lieu of a theme supporting my custom token types (which none of them will do), or forcing users to use a new custom theme.

Comment: that will force your users to use a particular theme, otherwise the default colors make the code unreadable for some themes, you can specify all the colors for textmate scopes in the settings for the theme overrides

Comment: ...huh? I do *not* want to force user to use a custom theme. That's precisely why I want to provide *default* values, that can either be implemented in a theme or overridden by users directly.

Comment: having default values makes no sense to put in a language definition, just create the textmate scopes and hope theme designers pick up the new names like some have for C++ and Python

Comment: I also have this question. It seems like a deficiency to me that you can't give a default colouring, you can't say "for a basically dark theme use red by default, for a basically light theme use blue by default" or whatever.

Comment: What I've seen done in the "log view" extension is to apply two scope names, but I suspect that this isn't really intended to work, I've seen no documentation that says it should. You specify two names, the first of which you pick based on the colour it is in the standard themes, and the second one your custom scope name that people can use for customisation. Seems like a hack to me.